# How to return a JSObject from a C/C++ function in Spidermonkey 38

Tags: spidermonkey

I want to create a JSObject in a C/C++ function and return it for use in the callee. I'm struggling with the official docs because the necessary information is a bit scattered and the guides are full of obsolete information and don't cover very few real-world scenarios.

Ignoring the parts that seem to refer to obsolete versions, the [cookbook](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Cookbook) shows examples calling `args.rval().setInt32()`, `setDouble()`, and `setNull()`. However, the [reference for JS::CallArgs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS::CallArgs#Methods_inherited_from_JS.3A.3ACallArgsBase) says `rval()` returns a `MutableHandleValue` which [doesn't appear to have those setter methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS::MutableHandle#Methods). Did they mean `rval()->set...`, which would work via its `->` and/or casting operator?

Then the [code example on the CallArgs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS::CallArgs#Description) additionally shows using the use of CallArgs' `set()` method. What's the difference between that and the above methods? Would `set()` and `setObject()` both ensure my new object is correctly registered with the GC?

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust MDN too much for SpiderMonkey, it's usually out of date or incomplete. The `MutableHandle<Value>` specialization implements [MutableValueOperations](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?q=MutableValueOperations&redirect=true&case=true), which includes `setObject()` among others.

So for example what you might want to do in your case:

```
static boolean
Test(JSContext* cx, unsigned argc, Value* vp) {
  CallArgs args = CallArgsFromVp(argc, vp);
  RootedObject obj(cx, JS_NewPlainObject(cx);
  if (!obj)
    return false;
  args.rval().setObject(*obj);
  return true;
}
```

`set` is different for all the different MutableHandle specializations. I.e. for `MutableHandle<JSString>` you could use it to set a `JSString*`.